# Is Black Mirror: Bandersnatch a game?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, scope

Wikipedia calls [*Black Mirror: Bandersnatch* (2018)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Mirror:_Bandersnatch) an "interactive movie," a term which it [defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_movie) as

> [...] a **video game** that presents its gameplay in a cinematic, scripted manner, often through the use of full-motion video [...]

In this respect, *Bandersnatch* is similar to many of the interactive stories made by Telltale Games, which I assume are on-topic.

**Can I ask questions about *Bandersnatch* here, or should I take them to [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com) instead?**

Comment: I don't see why we couldn't field the odd question about the interactive portions of this, although [Movies & TV deemed it on-topic for them](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4404/4174), so it may just be safer to ask over there

Comment: @Robotnik: That's fair, but I notice they are getting questions of the form "How do I win/get a happy ending/get some other outcome?" and I imagine those would be on-topic here... right?

Comment: I personally see no issue with it, it's interactive, it features multiple different paths and choices to make. It makes me think of those "interactive CD" full-motion-video games of the mid-90s.

Comment: I've found that if a question is on-topic on Arqade and another site, you're better off asking on the other site.

Comment: @Studoku: A *very large* subset of video games are on-topic on SFF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding my comments into an answer for posterity:

---

Personally, I see no issues with asking questions about Bandersnatch here. Bandersnatch is an interactive story-driven adventure in a similar vein to a "Choose your own adventure" story. It shares elements with those "interactive CD" full-motion-video games of the mid-90s, or as a more modern equivalent, to Telltale games like The Walking Dead, Minecraft: Story Mode, or Back to the Future.

In terms of the medium, that hardly matters. We've fielded questions about [Google Logo Doodles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-doodles), [Google Maps](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-pokemon), ([Twice!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-pacman)), and even [Browser Error Screens](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/downasaur), because of the mini-games these mediums contained, 'Netflix' is just another medium with the capacity to deliver gameplay. Bandersnatch features multiple different paths, choices to make, and different endings depending on those choices. It can be replayed too, making different decisions will produce a different experience and ultimately a different outcome/ending.

So yes, I think it should be fine to ask questions about Bandersnatch here. Do note that Movies & TV deemed it [on-topic for them](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4404/4174) too, so depending on your question and the sort of answer you seek, you might consider asking it there.